# Unable to display Pivot point in bar graph in MP Android Chart

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I have been playing around with MP Android chart. However I am unable to display the pivot point (0,0) in X and Y co-ordinates resp. 
These values only get shown if I have a low x and Y co-ordinate for the bar graph.
Upon higher value, the bar graph gets focused to the points in the bar chart where the value correspond.

Have a look at the image below :

[image: Bar Graph Android (Mp Android Chart)]

The x axis value below 20 have been vanished.

Also when the X & y pivot points (0,0) are do visible, there are these extra lines of Y axis that extrude below the pivot point. See the image below :

[image: Bar Graph 2 (Mp Android Chart)]

Please help me resolve these issues. Here is my code :

```
BarData data = new BarData(labels, (ArrayList) dataset);
 barChart.setData(data);
 barChart.animateY(3000);
 barChart.setPivotX(0);
 barChart.setPivotY(0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code below would help you to remove the grid lines. You can select the ones that fit yours.

> ```
>     XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
>     YAxis yAxisL = barChart.getAxisLeft();
>     YAxis yAxisR = barChart.getAxisRight();
>     xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
>     xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
>     xAxis.setDrawLabels(false);
>     yAxisL.setDrawAxisLine(false);
>     yAxisL.setDrawLabels(false);
>     yAxisR.setDrawGridLines(false);
>     yAxisR.setDrawAxisLine(false);
>     yAxisR.setDrawLabels(false);
>     //remove horizontal lines
>     AxisBase axisBase = barChart.getAxisLeft();
>     axisBase.setDrawGridLines(false);
> ```

I hope it helps if not yuo can reply with an image and I might be able to help. Just recently did something  of this nature.

Comment: Thankx man. The code worked perfectly :) Been looking for this solution for long ! Posting the exact code as an ans below.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment. With my best understanding, For the 1st one, 
you can try this.

```
YAxis yAxis = barChart.getAxisLeft();
yAxis.setAxisMinValue(0);
```

Then the chart will print from zero values.

For the second one, try to set the XAxis labels position to bottom.

```
 XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
 xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
```

Comment: Thanku for the help. However now I am getting some extra y-axis line along with the intended ones.

Comment: Sorry X-axis lines not y.

Comment: Is it solved your problem? In witch bar you are getting the lines? 1st one or the 2nd one?

Comment: I have posted the image below.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it [ with some help ;) ]. For anyone who might be facing this issue, below is the complete code with image :

```
    //For pinch zoom
    barChart.setPinchZoom(false);

    //To enable/disable barChart scaling upon 2 fingers expansion on the chart
    barChart.setScaleXEnabled(false);
    barChart.setScaleYEnabled(false);

    //To disable double tap zoom
    barChart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);

    barChart.animateY(3000);

    XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
    YAxis yAxisL = barChart.getAxisLeft();
    YAxis yAxisR = barChart.getAxisRight();

    yAxisL.setAxisMinValue(0f);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
    xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true);
    xAxis.setDrawLabels(true);
    yAxisL.setDrawAxisLine(true);
    yAxisL.setDrawLabels(true);
    yAxisL.setDrawZeroLine(true);
    yAxisR.setDrawGridLines(false);
    yAxisR.setDrawAxisLine(true);
    yAxisR.setDrawLabels(false);
    //remove horizontal lines
    AxisBase axisBase = barChart.getAxisLeft();
    axisBase.setDrawGridLines(true);
```

[image]

Cheers :) :)